# Are these subsets homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

Are the two subsets of the Euclidean Plane $[0,1]\times[0,1)$ and
$[0,1)\times[0,1)$ homeomorphic or not?

My attempt:

We need to find a bijective function $f$ from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1)$ such that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are both continuous. If $f$ is continuous then for $U\subseteq [0,1)$, we have that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $[0,1]$ if $U$ is open in $[0,1)$. Using the identity map and any open subset of $[0,1)$ we see that the pre-image is open in $[0,1]$ so they are homeomorphic.

Does this make sense?

Comment: You made many mistakes. Let $A=[0,1]\times[0,1[,B=[0,1[\times[0,1[$. The identity map $id:A\to B$ cannot be defined because $B$ is a proper subset of $A$. On the other hand, to conclude that two spaces are homeomorphic by definition you have to prove that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous. Even if you were right and $f$ were continuous, you must show that $f^{-1}$ is also continuous to get the conclusion.

Comment: The biggest mistake in your post is that it's simply not true that we have to find a bijection from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1)$ which is continuous and has a continuous inverse. There is no such bijection, but nonetheless there _is_ such a bijection from $[0,1]\times [0,1)$ onto $[0,1)\times[0,1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to address this in somewhat detailed form and using elementary methods.

First, let us map the square $S$ (possibly with some boundary points removed) homeomorphically onto the disk $D$ (with corresponding boundary points removed). For convenience, I will take $S = [-1,1] \times [-1,1]$  and $D$ = unit disk, which is inscribed in $S$. We don't lose any generality by doing this since it is very easy to show that any two squares in the plane are homeomorphic (and similarly for disks). (Compose a dilation with a translation; these are both homeomorphisms, so their composition is also a homeomorphism.)

I will construct a map $f:D \to S$ piecewise, by cutting $D$ into the four cardinal quadrants delimited by the two lines $y = \pm x$. In the eastern quadrant, using polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$ (so that $-\pi/4 \leq \theta \leq \pi/4$), define $$f(r,\theta) = \left( \frac{r}{\cos \theta},\theta\right).$$ Note that $f$ is continuous.
For a fixed angle $\theta$, as we move from the center of the disk ($r=0$) to the boundary ($r=1$), the corresponding point on the square $S$ moves from the center of the square to the boundary of the square. On the western quadrant, we use the same formula except that the fist coordinate has a minus sign.

Analogously, on the northern quadrant, define $$f(r,\theta) = \left( \frac{r}{\sin \theta},\theta\right),$$ and finally add a minus sign to the first coordinate to define $f$ on the southern quadrant.

By the [pasting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma), these glue together to form a continuous map $f:D \to S$. Moreover, it is easily seen to be bijective (this was the point of the construction). [As $D$ is compact and $S$ is Hausdorff, $f$ is a homeomorphism](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Bijection_from_Compact_to_Hausdorff_is_Homeomorphism).

Note that $f$ maps the boundary of $D$ homeomorphically onto the boundary of $S$, so that it interacts well with the removal of boundary points from either space. Notably, the square $[-1,1] \times [-1,1)$ is mapped onto the disk with the boundary arc $\{\pi/4 \leq \theta \leq 3\pi/4\}$ removed, and the square $[-1,1) \times [-1,1)$ is mapped onto the disk with the boundary arc $\{-\pi/4 \leq \theta \leq 3\pi/4\}$ removed. The problem is reduced to showing that a disk with a compact, proper boundary arc of length $a$ removed is homeomorphic to a disk with a compact, proper boundary arc of length $b$ removed (for some $0 < a < b < 2\pi$).

Up to some rotation (which is a homeomorphism), we may assume that the removed arc on the first (resp. second) disk starts at $(1,0)$ and ends at $(1,a)$ (resp. $(1,b)$) (still in polar coordinates). Identify an automorphism $g$ of the circle with a continuous map $g:[0,2\pi] \to [0,2\pi]$ such that $g(0) \equiv g(2\pi) \mod 2\pi$. Then we may describe the automorphism $h:D \to D$ we seek through the following slight perturbation of the identity map, which restricts to a piecewise-linear map on each circle $\{r = \mathit{const}\}$:
$$h(r,\theta) = \begin{cases} \left(r,\frac{b}{a}\theta\right) & \text{if $0 \leq \theta \leq a$} \\ \left(r,\frac{2\pi-b}{2\pi-a}(\theta-2\pi)\right) & \text{if $a \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$} \end{cases}.$$

This fixes $(r,0)$ and sends $(r,a)$ to $(r,b)$; moreover, it is easily seen to be a homeomorphism. This concludes the proof.

Comment: Thanks - if someone else didn't I was going to, but I didn't really want to, heh. (Not that I actually read it, just assuming it's more or less right...)

Comment: @alex-provost Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

They're homeomorphic since both of them are homeomorphic to the closed unit disc in $R^2$  with an arc removed on its boundary.

Comment: Well no. For one set an arc on the boundary is removed and a whole arc on the boundary remains. For the other set only one point on the boundary remains. Which actually proves they're not homeomorphic...

Comment: Both of them are the squares $I=[0,1]\times I$ with sides removed on the boundary, if you smooth the boundary you obtain a unit disc without an arc

Comment: You're right - I had the picture wrong in my head, sorry.

Comment: @TsemoAristide can you elaborate on what you mean by "arc removed on the boundary"? Would the arc removed of the [0,1]×[0,1) be smaller than the arc removed of [0,1)x[0,1)?

Comment: I don't feel like this fully answers the question; even if one accepts that one can map the squares homeomorphically onto the disks inscribed within, one still has to prove that two disks with (closed, proper) boundary arcs of distinct length removed are homeomorphic.

Comment: Ideally I'd like an answer that doesn't confuse an 2nd year undergrad please :)

Comment: @AlexProvost There are certainly details to be verified. But surely you're not saying that there's any _problem_ with those details...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich No, the argument works. But I can see how a 2nd year undergraduate student might struggle when trying to rigorously justify the claims. I might flesh out this argument in an answer of my own.